# Can Python's string .format() be made safe for untrusted format strings?

Tags: python, security

I'm working on a web app where users will be able to supply strings that the server will then substitute variables into.

Preferably I'd like to use [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) `format()` syntax and I'm looking at the feasibility of overriding methods in `Formatter` to make it secure for untrusted input.

Here are the risks I can see with `.format()` as it stands:

- Padding lets you specify arbitrary lengths, so `'{:>9999999999}'.format(..)` could run the server out of memory and be a DOS. I'd need to disable this.
- Format lets you access the fields inside objects, which is useful, but it's creepy that you can access dunder variables and start drilling into bits of the standard library. There's no telling where there might be a `getattr()` that has side effects or returns something secret. I would whitelist attribute/index access by overriding `get_field()`.
- I'd need to catch some exceptions, naturally.

My assumptions are:

- None of the traditional C format string exploits apply to Python, because specifying a parameter is a bounds-checked access into a collection, rather than directly popping off the thread's stack.
- The web framework I'm using escapes every variable that's substituted into a page template, and so long as it's the last stop before output, I'm safe from cross-site scripting attacks emerging from de-escaping.

What are your thoughts? Possible? Impossible? Merely unwise?

---

Edit: Armin Ronacher outlines a nasty information leak if you don't filter out dunder variable access, but seems to regard securing `format()` as feasible:

```python
{local_foo.__init__.__globals__[secret_global]}
```

[Be Careful with Python's New-Style String Format | Armin Ronacher's Thoughts and Writings](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2016/12/29/careful-with-str-format/)

*Personally, I didn't actually go the untrusted `format()` route in my product, but am updating for the sake of completeness*

Comment: Sounds unwise. Can't you just use `replace()`?

Comment: Well, for a start replace() needs a pass for each variable that might be in the string, which will scale horribly.

Comment: Lemmie expand on that seeing as I missed my chance to edit that. My use case is a MUD-like situation where I'm going to be doing a ton of string formatting with lots of potential variables.

I could go back to a weaker form of string formatting like `string.Template`, but being able to refer to the fields inside objects is very useful in my case too. It's something I can emulate by building a parameter map of every field from every argument in every call, but it'd be reassuring to have something that scales better.

Comment: Craig, maybe start defining a subset of `.format()` features you actually need. You may then check the format string itself, or make your own template language that maps to `.format()` format strings.

Comment: Suspect this falls under unwise, likewise with Python 3.6 using f-string literals seems a security risk with any user-entered data.

Answer (score 9):

Good instinct.  Yes,  an attacker being able to supply arbitrary format string is a vulnerability under python.

- The denial of service is probably the most simple to address.  In
  this case, limiting the size of the string or the number of operators
  within the string will mitigate this issue.  There should be a
  setting where no reasonable user will need to generate a string with
  more variables than X,  and this amount of computation isn't at risk
  of being exploited in a DoS attack.
- Being able to access attributes within an object could be dangerous. 
  However, I don't think that the `Object` parent class has any useful
  information.  The object supplied to the format would have to contain
  something sensitive.  In any case,  this type of notation can limited
  with a **regular expression**.
- If the format strings are user supplied then a user might need to
  know the error message for debugging. However,  error mesages can
  contain senstive information such as local paths or class names. Make
  sure to limit the information that an attacker can obtain.

Look over the [python format string specification](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) and forbid functionality you don't want the user to have with a regex.

Comment: Or better still, *allow* functionality that you do want to support, so when you upgrade to a new version of Python with new (and potentially dangerous) format options, you don't get caught out.

Comment: @Michael  yeah i agree a whitelist approach would be better.

Answer (score 4):

This simple Formatter override blocks users from accessing attributes. It still allows formatting and conversion of types.

```
from string import Formatter
class SafeFormatter(Formatter):
        def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
            if '.' in field_name or '[' in field_name:
                raise Exception('Invalid format string.')
            return super().get_field(field_name,args,kwargs)

form = SafeFormatter()
fname = form.format(format,num=1,id='hello')
```