# Is allowing user input in python's format() a security risk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, string-formatting, user-input

Would it be risky to format any string a user entered with Python's format() function, with arguments/values coming from user input too ?
(e.g. `user_input_string.format(*user_input_args)`)

Comment: Define *risky*...

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon Thanks, I didn't find this when searching.

Answer (score -2):

The operation itself is not risky, event if the user enters a Python vaid expression - that is not `eval` ed.

If the result is intended to go in a SQL database, you should consider quoting it before building the SQL string.

Comment: This answer is not true and potentially dangerous. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356649/can-pythons-string-format-be-made-safe-for-untrusted-format-strings).

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the `user_input_string` and the formating template was hardcoded in my mind. Anyway, template strings are usually not supposed to be provided by end users.